# Updating shared data with Twisted

Tags: python, twisted

How can I share a blob of data using a Twisted server, while at the time time periodically updating that data in the background?:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet import task
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.resource import Resource

data = 1

def update_data():
    data += 1

class DataPage(Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    def render_GET(self, request):
        return "<html><body>%s</body></html>" % (data, )

root = Resource()
root.putChild("data", DataPage())
factory = Site(root)
reactor.listenTCP(8880, factory)

m = task.LoopingCall(update_data)
m.start(10.0)

print "running"
reactor.run()
```

The above code does not work because of the following exception:

```
C:\temp>python discovery.py
Unhandled error in Deferred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "discovery.py", line 23, in <module>
    m.start(10.0)
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\task.py", line 163, in start
    self()
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\task.py", line 194, in __call__
    d = defer.maybeDeferred(self.f, *self.a, **self.kw)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "c:\python25\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 102, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "discovery.py", line 10, in update_data
    data += 1
exceptions.UnboundLocalError: local variable 'data' referenced before assignment
```

I would like HTTP clients to access, in this example, http://127.0.0.1:8880/data and retrieve the current value of data, while at the same time have some other task scheduled to update data every so often.

Moreover, I don't really want to use LoopingCall() because I may want to vary the interval depending on whether the update succeeds or not; the update will be some sort of remote API call.  Can I use CallLater() in some fashion instead?

I'm sure this is a stupid question!  Thanks.

EDIT: thouis helped with properly making the data variable global.  For those that follow, here's how to fit `callLater()` into the code:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet import task
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.resource import Resource

data = 1

def update_data():
    global data
    data += 1
    reactor.callLater(10, update_data)

class DataPage(Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    def render_GET(self, request):
        return "<html><body>%s</body></html>" % (data, )

root = Resource()
root.putChild("data", DataPage())
factory = Site(root)
reactor.listenTCP(8880, factory)

update_data()

print "running"
reactor.run()
```

This code still feels a bit hacky.  I don't like declaring module-level variables, let alone using global variables.  I welcome any suggestions that avoid such practises and make the code look cleaner and more re-usable.

Comment: You can also make `data` an attribute of the `DataPage`.  Or an attribute of some other object that the `DataPage` has access to.

Comment: I agree with JPC.  The DataPage seems like a much better place to store it.

Comment: I'll probably make data and the function responsible for peroidically updating it child members of DataPage, and abstract out the updating process into a separate class.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a global def to update_data():

```
def update_data():
    global data
    data += 1
```

Comment: Also, CallLater seems like a reasonable way to do what you describe, but more details would be helpful.  You might also need to start worrying about locking if multiple threads will be accessing and updating the shared resource.

Comment: Thank you, I am truly an idiot. RE: threads.  My understanding of Twisted is that a given reactor is only run in a single thread.  Hence do I really need to worry about locking, even if I use CallLater()?  What more details do you require?

Comment: Not if you just use CallLater, no.

Comment: Your understanding of the reactor as running in a single thread is totally correct.  You *can* use threads with Twisted, but it's all very explicit with `callInThread` and `callFromThread` - unless you call an API like that, you're not using threads.